# Is there a better LinkedList threadsafe implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, concurrency

I'm using a LinkedList and switching between storing data that i'm getting through updates, performing computations on it and removing old updates.
To perform this, I have to lock the reading and sampling section but this comes with a perfomance hit.
Since I'm constantly adding and removing nodes I thought LinkedList is the best datastructure for this task (to my understanding, using a list for this would incur mulitple actions of copying the list)
As far as I'm aware there's no thread-safe implemation of LinkedList.
I'm running this code on a large volume of data, and it take hours to complete.
Is there a way I could speed it up?

edit: I'm adding nodes to the end of the list and removing from the start of it

```
  private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Update> _UpdatesQueue = new   ConcurrentQueue<Update>();
  private volatile bool _AddingUpdates = false;
  public void InsertUpdate(Update update)
        {
            _UpdatesQueue.Enqueue(update);
            if (_AddingUpdates)
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (_updateQueueLock)
            {
                if (_AddingUpdates)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _AddingUpdates = true;
            }
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                lock (_updateQueueLock)
                {
                    Update lastupdate = null;
                    while (_UpdatesQueue.TryDequeue(out update))
                    {
                        updateWindow.AddLast(update);
                    }
                }
            }).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                _AddingUpdates = false;
            });
        }

        private volatile bool _Sampling = false;
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<Timestamp, Action<float>>> _RequestsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<Timestamp, Action<float>>>();

        public void GetFeatureAtTime(Timestamp time, Action<float> valueCallback)
        {
            _RequestsQueue.Enqueue(new Tuple<Timestamp, Action<float>>(time, valueCallback));
            if (_Sampling)
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (_updateQueueLock)
            {
                if (_Sampling)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _Sampling = true;
            }
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                lock (_updateQueueLock)
                {
                    Timestamp lastTime = null;
                    while (_RequestsQueue.TryPeek(out var request))
                    {
                        GetFeatureAtTimeInternal(request.Item1, request.Item2, out var haveEnoughData);
                        if (haveEnoughData)
                        {
                            _RequestsQueue.TryDequeue(out _);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).ContinueWith(x => _Sampling = false);
        }
```

From what i'm seeing in the Concurrency Visualizer tool in VS, 76% of the cpu is spent on synchornization.
Also, sampling can sometimes be a leangthy action as compared to insertion.

Comment: What the `updateWindow.AddLast(update);` line is doing?

Comment: adding an Update object to the end of the LinkedList

Comment: And what's the point of `ConcurrentQueue<Update> _UpdatesQueue`? Why don't you just call `lock (updateWindow) updateWindow.AddLast(update)`?

Comment: The idea was to prevent multiple threads waiting at the lock when inserting, instead they push updates into the the queue, and the first thread arriving also pulls from it and adds updates to the linkedlist

Comment: Re, "...I'm constantly adding and removing nodes..." Adding where? Removing from where? Have you considered whether your needs might be met by some existing library class that is designed specifically for use in multi-threaded programs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Comment: I've concidered using those, however none of them seems to provide the funcationality i'm looking for, i.e., quickly accessing the first and last item, storing specific items, and moving to previous \ next ones starting from those stored ones.

Comment: @freakazoid so your code demonstrates an attempt to fix the problem, not the original problem itself. I guess that your attempt was not successful (otherwise you wouldn't have posted this question), so why don't you show us your original problem, so that we can propose a hopefully better solution?